# How to clone from a Windows server to Mac client through ssh in Git?

Tags: git, ssh

```
ssh user@example.com
```

Works just fine.
But when I tried

```
git clone user@example.com:/d/myrepo.git
```

I got

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am running a Bitvise SSH Server.
Help!!

Comment: Does the repo exist at that path?

Comment: @krsteeve The repo is in the D:\myrepo.git .Is that ok?

Comment: as you can login all right, run `ls -la /d/myrepo.git` to check the situation

Comment: @mnagel I tried and there is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

I use cydwin+openssh+cygwin-git instead of Bitvise SSH server.

```
git clone user@example.com:/cygdrive/d/myrepo.git
```

Works perfectly now.